# PHP: Switch() If{} other control structures

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement, logic

How do you execute logic with out the use of Switch or If?

For instance check_id_switch($id)

```
function check_id_switch($id){
    switch($id){
        case '1': 
        $HW = 'Hello, World!';
        break;
        default:
        $HW = 'Goodbye, World!';
        break;
     } 
  return $HW;
 }
```

Or instance check_id_if($id)

```
function check_id_if($id){
    if($id == 1){
     $HW = 'Hello, World!';
    }
   else{ 
   $HW = 'Goodbye, World!';
 }
return $HW;
}
```

Both of which functions check_id_switch($id) and check_id_if($id) will check the ID to it's reference.

How do I create the same logic as above without using if/switch statements in php? I would also like to avoid forloops.

There are multiple debates regarding performance for the switch/if but if there is another control structure does it under or out perform the aforementioned control structures?

Adding Login Script as an example of if statements. I've removed the backbone of the login script. You don't need to see the actions completed if true:false.  I just feel that the below is clunky and unclean.

```
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $errors = array();
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    $remember_choice = trim($_POST["remember_me"]);

    if($username == "")
    {
        $errors[] = ""; 
    }
    if($password == "")
    {

        $errors[] = "";
    }

    if(count($errors) == 0)
    {
        if(!usernameExists($username))
        {
            $errors[] = "";
        }
        else
        {
            $userdetails = fetchUserDetails($username);

            if($userdetails["active"]==0)
            {
                $errors[] = "";
            }
            else
            {
                $entered_pass = generateHash($password,$userdetails["password"]);

                if($entered_pass != $userdetails["password"])
                {
                    $errors[] = "";
                }
                else
                {

                    // LOG USER IN
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if` is more or less the simplest thing you can do in programming. I dare say it's the base of programming. There's close to no overhead when using `if`, even for lots of `if`s.

Comment: Create a simple array: `$arr = [1 => "Hello, World!", 2 => "Goodby, World!"];` and then: `echo $arr[$id];` and done..

Comment: @Rizier123 I like the train of thought and your response is very imaginative (which is what I asked for) but I don't believe accessing an array is a good substitute. As you wouldn't be able step through a process such as registering a user or checking a data table for a true/false return. Unless you can have specific examples?

Comment: If you want to combine the array solution with doing more that echo/return one value, you can put functions' names in your array and call it instead of echoing the value.

Comment: @Chris I don't really got your last comment ^. But if your asking how you can check if the id exists in the array, just do: `if(isset($arr[$id]))` and this will return true if you have an array element with the `$id` as key, otherwise false

Comment: My question would be how would you implement an array to create advanced logic that steps through a process of dynamic events? My ultimate goal in mind is: Avoid the use If statements. I have a report tool that gathers input data from my customer and builds dynamic output based on if true or if false so on so forth. My class is filled with if and switch statements. I want it to be clean and have a smaller footprint. Is there another Control Structure that allows for this?

Comment: Maybe show more code?

Comment: @caCtus I would but It's to long to post in a comment. Let's just say it looks like this 
   ` if(!isset($_POST)){
      if($username = ""){}
       if($password = ""){}
        if(!username_in_database($username)){}else{
         if(!hash_function($password) == $database_password){
         }else{  Login! } } } } } } }`
   
Again that was quick and has many syntax errors. But it iterates the point Im using 9 If structures to verify data and thats not counting the user class that alows use's If and switch to verify the data beig input.

Comment: @Chris "I would but It's to long to post in a comment": That's why you have an "edit" link down your post. ;)

Comment: @caCtus added bare bones version of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ternary` operator for the same as

```
function check_id_switch($id){
    return $HW = ($id == 1) ? 'Hello, World!' : 'Goodbye, World!';
}
```

Or you can simply use [Rizier's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732910/php-switch-if-other-control-structures#comment49522139_30732910) answer which he commented as

```
function check_id_switch($id = '2'){
    $arr = [1 => "Hello, World!", 2 => "Goodbye, World!"];
    return $arr[$id];
}
```

Comment: Would you use a ternary operator over an IF/Switch statement?

Comment: `switch` and `if` statement can get extended quite easy. With the ternary it gets unreadable pretty fast, so you might want to also give them an easy extendable version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732910/php-switch-if-other-control-structures#comment49522139_30732910 :) (Also your `isset()` call is a bit unnecessary, since the function needs an id as argument)

Comment: Yep that's easy extendable version and pretty fast too. Didn't have it in mind really quick one.@Rizier123 I think this'll make that case too if we don't use `isset()`

Comment: It's a One liner why to use `if else` if you simply can normalize your code @Chris